# 〜の vs 〜と before 分かる

Tags: particles, verbs

Sometimes I see ~の(が/は) used before the verb 分かる, and sometimes と(は). Is there a difference in meaning or grammar between these two?

For example, are both below sentences correct and do they have the same nuance? (My intention is to mean "I understand it is red")

> 赤なのが分かる。

> 赤だと分かる。

Is there any major difference between 〜の and 〜と with this verb? If so, can someone give me a proper example sentence for each that illustrates its usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are correct and with the same meaning but different in grammar

赤なの = 赤(a noun) + な(a 連体形 of verbal auxiliary だ) + の(a postpositional particle used in nominalization)

赤だと = 赤(a noun) + だ(a verbal auxiliary だ) + と(a postpositional particle)

For example, 彼が先生だと分かった and 彼が先生なのが分かった.

Comment: Thanks! Is there really no nuance difference or preference for certain cases? If I do google searches of certain phrases for one vs the other I get different hit counts, though I know this may not be a meaningful test.

Comment: I thought the difference in detail,  so I feel と分かる is a bit more literary than のが分かる.